# Import an image from an Astro.props variable

Tags: astrojs

How can I import an image in an astro file when the URL of the image comes from a Prop.

```
---
const { 
    thumbnail,
} = Astro.props.blog_entry.data;

//this works in DEV, but throws an error when executing the build command
const { default : thumbnail_url } = await import(thumbnail.url);
---
<!--- ... --->
<img src={thumbnail_url.src} alt={thumbnail.alt}/>
<!--- ... --->
```

During the build command, this error appears: `Cannot find module 'D:\src\assets\image.jpg'...`. Which is not the actual location of the file.

---

When I put the URL directly to the `<img/>` Tag like:

```
<img src={thumbnail.url} alt={thumbnail.alt}/>
```

The URL does not get parsed and the production file ends with the original string ("/src/assets/image.jpg").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem where I had to create ~100 cards from json and images are stored in src/assets/* folder

- **If you don't want image optimization by astro**
  move all the image files (one which needs to be dinamically imported) into the public folder and use path relative to the public folder
  but you can't use the image optimization functionality of Astro since you are using img tag and not Image from astro it won't matter
- **If you want to use image optimization**then images should be inside src\

1: you can optimize image using other methods and then use public folder

2:
using dynamic import completely breaks either in production or dev
the only working solution I got

```
const images:{[index:string]:any} ={}
await Astro.glob("/src/assets/images/*.jpg").then((files) => {
    files.forEach((file) => {
        const name = file.default.src.split(".")[0].split("/").pop()
        images[name]=file.default
    });
});

places.forEach((place)=>{
    const image = images[place.name]
    if(image)
        place.image=image
    else
        place.image = fallbackImage
})

<ul>
    {
        places.map((place) => {
            return (
                <li>
                    <Image
                        src={place.image}
                        alt={place.name}
                        width={Math.round((100 * 16) / 9)}
                        height={100}
                        format="webp"
                        loading="lazy"
                    />
                </li>
            );
        })
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, i also tried this method of preloading all images first but i ended up using a different solution (for some scenareos, since it was not fitting for all). If you are using the contents folder to store the data of your `places`, you can use the `image` validator that imports and transforms the string into `imageMetadata`. Docs [here](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/images/#images-in-content-collections).

Comment: Thank you. With your solution, I was able to use the Astro Picture component while mapping pictures coming from a Json file.